# бэкап mysql из PHP скрипта

Tags: php, mysql, резервное-копирование

доброго

локально поставит OpenServer ( PHP7+MySQL5.7 ). Накидал простой PHP скрипт, для проверки подключения к БД ( SELECT * FROM `моя_таблица` ). Ест-но захотелось большего, т.к. тянусь к знаниям

попробовал выполнить такое

```
$user = "root";
$host = "127.0.0.1:3306";
$pass = "123";
$base = "mytestbase";
$out  = "databaseX.sql";
$sql  = "mysqldump -u".$user." -h".$host." -p".$pass." ".$base." > ".$out."";


runsql($sql);//запросы типа INSERT/SELECT/UPDATE/DELETE/SHOW - идут отлично
```

Подскажите, как дописать код, что бы бэкап все же получалось сделать?

p.s. да, я знаю, что по модному открывать консоль, и каждый раз руками вбивать настройки в место запуска файла. интересует именно выполнить команду из файла

Comment: MySQLdump - не команда MySQL, а внешнее приложение. Запускайте его как обычный исполняемый файл на удалённом сервере. Если прав хватит, конечно...

Comment: O_o вы мне сейчас поведали больше поисковика. т.е. я так понял что средствами mysql команд бэкаб делать другой командой?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/backup-methods.html метод "Making Delimited-Text File Backups". PS. Поисковик надо задействовать только после того, как прочитана и усвоена ВСЯ документация на продукт.

Comment: оно, спасибо. проблема была в теории

Answer (score -2):

Т.к. mysqldump - это внешняя программа, то для выполнения команды следует использовать функию `exec`:

```
$result=exec("mysqldump -u".$user." -h".$host." -p".$pass." ".$base,$out);
```